# SetUp Apache Derby Database in IntelliJ Community

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby

I am using IntelliJ for a java project. And for the first time I wanted to try Apache Derby but I don't know how to configure it. I downloaded [db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin.zip](http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache//db/derby/db-derby-10.15.2.0/db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin.zip) and the library [db-derby-10.15.2.0-lib.zip](http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache//db/derby/db-derby-10.15.2.0/db-derby-10.15.2.0-lib.zip). 
The files I downloadit from [here.](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.2.0.cgi)

I don't even know if it's possible to configure in IntelliJ 2019. If someone have experience with this please guide me to configure this!

Thanks in advance!

*P.s. I don't know if this is the righr place to post this question.*

Comment: Does this help? https://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html

Comment: I check that but...no

Comment: Are you wanting to connect to a Derby database and write queries? If so the community version will not allow you to do that - you need the paid version. If you mean you want your application/program to connect to it and run queries say using JDBC that is possible but you'll need to give more details of your project setup.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to use IntelliJ as a database client, where you can examine tables and execute SQL statements on the fly? Or do you want to write your own program which should connect to a Derby database? Which mode do you use? Embedded or client-server?

Comment: I want to use IntelliJ as database client, to create database and tables.. and then to write code who will do something with that database... Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTrJoXD5mNw&list=PL2PXcjrPJAVVPI2xjzToGCpwZ9BqV82GC&index=28  ( it is in italian im using auto translator from youtube)

Comment: In addition to the quick_start link posted by @mike above, you can also look at JDBC tutorials such as: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html